# adb pull File from Specific Folder

Tags: android

Please guide me, I need to pull File (with specific format) from the Phone Location (inside folder), Ex:  "ABC****" file from "My_Folder_Date/time" Folder.

Command:   `adb Pull /sdcard/My_Folder*/ABC* <Destination path>`

Answer (score 1):

Got the Answer, Thanks.  Copied file to temp folder (sdcard/tmp) in Phone and then performed ADB Pull.

Command:

```
adb Shell cp /sdcard/My_Folder*/ABC /sdcard/tmp
```

then,

```
adb pull /sdcard/tmp destination_path
```